# saving results from spark rdd.foreach() in a new rdd / extensive regex usage

Tags: python, regex, apache-spark

From an analytics department i get a python function with about 5.000 different regular expressions. This function will be used inside a map().

Essantially my python code looks like:

```
rdd_result = rdd.map(f)

def f(x):
    import re
    if re.search('^bar*', x) is not None: return 456        
    if re.search('^.*foo', x) is not None: return 123
    return 999
```

In reality f(x) is much more complex.

The computation time is not really great. In python regex will be compiled automatically on the first call and will be executed much faster on following calls. In my understanding ther won´t be any benefit of the compilation as with calling f(x) from a map() no previous compiled regex will be available. And that despite the fact that f(x) will be called millionfold.

My idea was to compile the regex by hand (or let python do i automatically) and iterate over the rdd by hand with rdd.foreach(). The problem ist that this will, regarding my understanding, be accomplished on the driver. This will lead to a memory problem.

And i´ll have the results of the foreach() in memory and not in a rdd_result as i need it for further computations. I have no good feeling creating a new rdd with sc.parallelize() regarding the big amount of data.

So my question: map() is essentially for altering data from an rdd and saving the result in a new rdd. Is there a easy way to save the results from an foreach() in an rdd?

Or any other ideas for other approaches to my problem?

Thank you all!

Comment: It is hard to tell without real-world data - either form a huge regex *outside*  `f(x)` or use a parser. The code provided so far seems redundant as the string is searched multiple times.

Comment: The code for f(x) should only be an example and has no further meaning.

Comment: You could use `mapPartitions` but as far as I am aware Python automatically caches compiled patterns so benefits should be minimal. You can also pass compiled expression with closure or as an argument.